# Why multiply noise and random walk values by some constant value

Tags: imu, calibration, robot-calibration

I was exploring calculation of IMU intrinsics (random walk and noise values) for IMU using kalibr tool using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtzmsuJemgI) video.  At timestamp [25:48](https://youtu.be/BtzmsuJemgI?si=72q7A4N5AyiuZnVz&t=1548), Patrick says, "typically we dont use values generated by Allan Variance ROS directly and we inflate them by order of 10 times, may be by 20".

The same thing is done at [timestamp 10:03 of this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Bsd5kLgHtM&t=603s). Michael multiplies the value read from Allan Deviation by 60 but without giving much reason.

Why is it so? Is there any mathematical or empirical significance to it? Or is it just that moving robot might incur more noise and bias for IMU than when calculated for steady IMU?